# Number of permutations when $1$ does not immediately precede $2$ ...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many permutations of
    $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ are there such that $1$ does not immediately
    precede $2$, $2$ does not immediately precede $3$, and so forth up
    to $8$ not immediately preceding $9$? One obvious example of such
    a permutation might be $987654321$, but there are many others,
    such as $132465879$ or $351724698$.}

Ok so I know the total number of permutations with no restrictions is 9!, but I'm not sure how to calculate it when the numbers have to precede each other. Thanks in advance for any help.